# How do I initialize Bootstrap Tagsinput with Ruby on Rails and Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tags-input

**Background and Tools**:

I am using the [Bootstrap Tags Input jQuery plugin](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples) with Rails.

I am storing the plugin as `vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-tagsinput.js` and it's stylesheet as `vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-tagsinput.css`.

I am tagging all of my Books in a digital library Rails app.

**Problem**:

If I navigate directly to `Book#new` or `Book#edit`, tags work as expected from the project's demo page.

However, if I navigate to the `Books#edit` or `Books#new` page via a link click on another page, then my text input is formatted as a typical html text input with the comma-separated string `science,fiction,good,short` displayed.

**More Info**:
My input looks like this:

```
<input class="form-control tagsinput" data-role="tagsinput" id="books_tags"
name="books[tags]" type="text" value="science,fiction,good,short">
```

The `bootstrap-tagsinput.js` file has these lines at the bottom of the file:

```js
  /**
   * Initialize tagsinput behaviour on inputs and selects which have
   * data-role=tagsinput
   */
  $(function() {
    $("input[data-role=tagsinput], select[multiple][data-role=tagsinput]").tagsinput();
  });
})(window.jQuery);
```

It seems that this initialization gets run by Rails and applies it's JavaScript magic to the `<input>` when entering a URL location directly, but not when navigating via links on pages.

**Question**:

**How do I get the initialization to run when navigating from another page?**

Comment: May be a turbolinks issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing the initialization code in `app/assets` instead of `vendor/assets` will run the initialization on page load.  The `bootstrap-tagsinput.js` library will still be loaded via `vendor/assets`, but the initialization will need to be run via `app/assets`.

Remove theses lines from `vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-tagsinput.js`:

```
  $(function() {
    $("input[data-role=tagsinput], select[multiple][data-role=tagsinput]").tagsinput();
  });
```

and place them in a JS file inside the asset pipeline: `app/assets/javascripts/books.js`.

```
  $(function() {
    $("input[data-role=tagsinput], select[multiple][data-role=tagsinput]").tagsinput();
  });
```

Moving the content will ensure that the initialization runs. Do not simply copy the lines over, or the initialization will run twice - and that will really mess up the appearance of your nifty tagsinput plugin.